My contact form with checkboxes recently stopped working
After my contact form always worked smoothly, the “send” function recently stopped working. The input fields are checked properly and are also output with the correct messages. The checkboxes are also checked and registered. The error message only appears when “sending”. However, I can't find this, but I assume that some variable is no longer current.
Can anyone help me with this? I pasted the script with PHP and HTML here.
My HTML
<form id="contact-form" accept-charset="utf-8" action="" method="POST">

              <div class="row contact-row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 contact-name">
                  <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Vorname *" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 contact-name">
                  <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Nachname *" required>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row contact-row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 contact-name">
                  <input name="street" id="street" type="text" placeholder="Stra&szlig;e *" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 contact-name">
                  <input name="number" id="number" type="text" placeholder="Nr. *" required>
                </div>
              </div>
                <div class="row contact-row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 contact-name">
                  <input name="zip" id="zip" type="text" placeholder="PLZ *" required>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 contact-name">
                  <input name="local" id="local" type="text" placeholder="Ort *" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row contact-row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 contact-name">
                  <input name="telefon" id="telefon" type="text" placeholder="Telefon *" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 contact-email">
                  <input name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="E-Mail *" required>
                </div>
              </div>

              <input name="sideID" id="sideID" type="hidden" value="1420">
              <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Info" rows="5" required>Informationen</textarea>


                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mb-30">
                <h6>Hinweise</h6>
                <ul class="checkboxes">
                  <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" name="check1" id="check1"  required>
                    <label for="check1">* Der ...</label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" name="check2" id="check2"  required>
                    <label for="check2">* Die ...  </label>
                  </li>

                </ul>
              </div>

              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-submit" value="Ihre Anfrage absenden" id="submit-message">
              <div id="msg" class="message"></div>
            </form>

My php
<?php 
    if($_POST) {

        $to = "test@test.de"; // Your email here
        $subject = 'Test Homepage'; // Subject message here
        
    }

    //Send mail function
    function send_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers){
        if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
            echo json_encode(array('info' => 'success', 'msg' => "Ihre Anfrage wurde erfolgreich gesendet."));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten! Ihre Anfrage wurde nicht gesendet."));
        }
    }

    //Check if $_POST vars are set
    if(!isset($_POST['firstname']) || !isset($_POST['lastname'])  || !isset($_POST['street']) || !isset($_POST['number']) || !isset($_POST['zip']) || !isset($_POST['local']) || !isset($_POST['telefon']) || !isset($_POST['email'])   || !isset($_POST['message'])  )
    {
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => 'Füllen Sie bitte alle Felder aus.'));
    }
    
    $check1 = isset($_POST['check1']) ? true : false;
    $check2 = isset($_POST['check2']) ? true : false;
    
    $sideID = $_POST['sideID'];

    

    //Sanitize input data, remove all illegal characters    
    $firstname    = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $lastname    = filter_var($_POST['lastname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $street    = filter_var($_POST['street'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $number    = filter_var($_POST['number'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $zip    = filter_var($_POST['zip'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $local    = filter_var($_POST['local'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $telefon    = filter_var($_POST['telefon'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email    = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    
    
    $message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    
    

    //Validation
    if($firstname == '') {
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Vornamen"));
        exit();
    }
    if($lastname == '') {
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "namen"));
        exit();
    }
    if($street == '') {
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Straße"));
        exit();
    }
    if($number  == '') {
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Hausnummer"));
        exit();
    }
    if($zip == '') {
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => " PLZ"));
        exit();
    }
    if($local == '') {
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Ort"));
        exit();
    }
    if($telefon == '') {
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Telefonnummer"));
        exit();
    }
    
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "gültige E-Mai "));
        exit();
    }
    if($message == ''){
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Nachricht vergessen."));
        exit();
    }
    if($check1 == false) {
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Datenschutzerkärung"));
        exit();
    }
    if($check2 == false) {
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Widerruf"));
        exit();
    }
    

    //Send Mail

        

    $headers = 'From: ' . $email .''. "\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    send_mail($to, $subject, 'Nachricht: ' .$message . "\r\n\n" .'Objekt-Nr: '.$sideID. "\r\n\n"  .'Vorname: '.$firstname. "\r\n"  .'Nachname: '.$lastname. "\r\n\n"  .'Strasse: '.$street. "\r\n"  .'Hausnummer: '.$number. "\r\n"  .'PLZ: '.$zip. "\r\n"  .'Ort: '.$local. "\r\n\n"  .'Telefon: '.$telefon. "\r\n\n" .'Datenschutz: '.$check1. "\r\n" .'Widerruf: '.$check2.  "\r\n\n" .'Email: '.$email, $headers);
?>


My Script
 var submitContact = $('#submit-message1'),
        message = $('#msg');

    submitContact.on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this);
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'send1.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            data: $('#contact-form1').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {

                if(data.info !== 'error'){
                    $this.parents('form').find('input[type=text],input[type=email],input[type=checkbox],textarea,select').filter(':visible').val('');
                    message.hide().removeClass('success').removeClass('error').addClass('success').html(data.msg).fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
                } else {
                    message.hide().removeClass('success').removeClass('error').addClass('error').html(data.msg).fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
                }
            }
        });
    });

I tried adding a value, but it didn't help.

check your browser dev console and network tab for possible errors. If found anything then add it here in your question, but before that try to resolve it on your end. I am talking about these 2 tabs: https://prnt.sc/gbjbhHLXMP8o

"The error message only appears when “sending”" - what error message, and on what line? What other debugging have you done? "but I assume that some variable is no longer current." - don't assume, check.

Does whichever SMTP server you're using to send emails allow you to send mails from any domain? I wonder if they've recently implemented some security that prevents Open Relay which means you need to send the email 'from' your address, and rely on the reply-to header for setting the reply address.

Is it possible that a form field has a name or id attribute that is no longer supported?
The browsers sometimes do not recognize that the check mark has been set.
The answer is
else {
echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten! Ihre Anfrage wurde nicht gesendet."));
}

@user24834436 your form is absolutely fine and works perfectly to send the data - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kudvLo09/ (you can look in the browser's Network tool at the request (which ultimately fails as there's no PHP script accessible, but it doesn't matter) and see the payload of the POST request when you submit the form). Nothing has changed in that respect. Did you not try to debug it already, and rule that out?

If you see that error then it's because mail returned false. If it returned false it's because it failed to send the email. You might need to check the mailserver logs to find out precisely why, but as droopsnoot says the fact you're faking other people's "from" addresses and sending emails from your server as if you were that person and are authenticated to send on their behalf...that is not a good sign. Most mail providers have blocked that for a long time, or are starting to do so now.

But also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail to see all the other things that can potentially go wrong with your mail, and try to rule each one out. If you switch to a modern email library such as PHPMailer it has full debug logging which would also allow you to see much more easily what's going on when you send the mail.

That was a good tip with the server.
It must actually have something to do with any security measures that may have been taken.
When I send myself an email from my server, it is delivered cleanly.

In that scenario if the email you're sending "from" is the same domain as your server, then that would be likely considered more acceptable by the mailserver.

Now I just have to see how I can make it possible for other people/ from servers to email me again.

You just make a default "from" address and put the email from the contact form into the message body and/or the reply-to field. Did you find a different way?

I don't understand what you mean? Can you show me using my example?

I mean if your website is mydomain.com then you must write something like $headers = 'From: noreply@mydomain.com\r\n". Your code is already putting $email in the reply-to field and in the email body, so you don't need to add anything for those parts. Using a "from" address which is part of your domain means that your mailserver genuinely has permission to send from that address.
